# ServiceStack IoC/DI: Registering classes in the Container - how to register all that implements a specific interface

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, servicestack

I have started looking into ServiceStack IoC/DI more closely, and it is working very nicely so far, when I for example use the manual registration approach:

```
container.AddScoped<IGeoService, GeoService>();
```

My property in the Service is then populated as expected:

```
public class MyNiceService : Service
{
    public IGeoService Geo { get; set; }
}
```

The above works and `Geo` is populated correctly.

The first thoughts are:

- Why is there an option to specify both the Interface and the concrete class?
- If I just add it to the container using `container.AddScoped<GeoService>();` then it should 'fit' the property, because GeoService implements the IGeoService?
- However, if I use `container.AddScoped<GeoService>();`, then, the DI fails, and my IGeoService property in the Services is null.
- If I change the property to `public GeoService Geo { get; set; }`, then the DI works.

*Auto-register all classes that implements an interface*

Preferably, I would like to find all classes that implements a specific Interface, and register all of those classes in the container, something like:

```
GetType().Assembly.GetTypes()
        .Where(x => x is IMyCoreService && x.IsClass && !x.IsAbstract)
        .Each(x => container.RegisterAutoWiredType(x));
```

but this fails, the `public GeoService Geo { get; set; }` is then null.

I appreciate some input, so I am doing things the correct way :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you register your dependency, it's always being registered it against a type. If you don't specify an interface then it will register it against its concrete Type which you would need to use in in your dependency properties. Likewise if you register the dependency against its interface you would need to use the interface in your dependency properties instead.

There's no implied behavior that registers a concrete type against all its interfaces it implements, what ever type it's registered against is the type you need to use to resolve it.

If you register a concrete dependency with:

```
container.RegisterAutoWiredType(typeof(GeoService));
```

Then it will get injected in Services that reference its concrete Type property:

```
public GeoService Geo { get; set; }
```

If you're saying it doesn't then I'm assuming your query isn't registering the type.

Comment: Alright, so that means that if I wanna use the Reflection approach (see above) and register with `container.RegisterAutoWiredType(x)`, there X is a Type, then the DI properties needs to be the concrete type.

Comment: @Ted Right, it uses the concrete Type.

Comment: So, there isnt a way to use the Reflection approach to load dependencies, and still use interface properties, they have to be concrete?

Comment: @Ted Use it’s overload, see IOC docs for examples https://docs.servicestack.net/ioc#autowire-registration You can only have 1 dependency per interface so your reflection is going to have to be able to extract the unique interface per Type which is why it’s not normally done via reflection like this as you want to be specific about which interface you use and your example suggests they all implement multiple interfaces given they all at least share the IMyCoreService interface.

Comment: Ah, I missed this one: `container.RegisterAutoWiredType(typeof(MyType),typeof(IMyType));`. And yes, I agree, its 1:1 relationship like you say. WE will prob  just have one concrete implementation, and so, using Reflection to load them all instead of manually. But, I also agree, its clearer with the manual approach. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

Not a true answer, but rather a partial answer focused on *"Why is there an option to specify both the Interface and the concrete class?"*.

### (Counter)example

Imagine that in addition to your current code you also have this class:

```
public class OtherGeoService : IGeoService { ... }
```

and this DI setup:

```
container.AddScoped<GeoService>();
container.AddScoped<OtherGeoService>();
```

Then the question becomes *"instance of which class should be injected as `IGeoService`?"*. This question has no easy answer from the DI framework perspective (albeit it might from your perspective), and that is why in most frameworks it is your responsibility to answer that question. So by writing

```
container.AddScoped<IGeoService, GeoService>();
```

you're basically saying *"if someone asks for `IGeoService`, give them a `GeoService`"*.

### Second side of the same coin

On the other hand, many classes that people usually register in DI containers implement various common interfaces like `IEnumerable`, `IDisposable` or `ISerializable`. If there were some elaborate implementation selection algorithms in action<sup>1</sup>, it would be very hard to determine (or at least not apparent) what exact type of object will be injected.

### Recap

I believe that these are two main reasons for why most (if not all) DI frameworks require such "verbose" dependency registration. You only get exactly what you ask for, and not *"the next best thing that technically 'fits' your requirements"*. Note that the decision is not controlled by the requesting code, so the *IoC* paradigm is not violated.

### OK, but WHY?

I understand that it might seem over-engineered for day-to-day use to a developer at the beginning of their journey into the programming world. I mean, it is completely reasonable to ask *"why would I ever provide more than one implementation of a service?"*, which boils down to *"why would I bother defining all those boilerplate interfaces if they're going to only have one implementation?"*.

In many (perhaps even most) cases you wouldn't have to. But there are good reasons to do it anyway:

- It stems from the "O" in SOLID programming principles. An interface only provides an abstraction of *"what a service can do"* and not *"how exactly does it do it"*. That way your services are clearly separated in terms of their business logic. At first it may seem unlikely, but there's a good chance that at some point you will be required to modify/replace parts of the application to suit new needs.
- It comes in very handy when writing unit tests. You can easily mock a dependency if it is an interface. It is far more messy (if at all possible) to mock concrete classes for testing purposes.<sup>2</sup>

---

<sup>1</sup> It is my personal opinion that no such algorithms should be in place, or at least you should try not to depend on them. That way you can almost painlessly switch the DI framework along the way without any side effects.

<sup>2</sup> It is widely believed that unit testing should not affect the design of the tested unit, i.e. you should not introduce a dependency or expose any functionality solely to allow or simplify its testing.